# Change external admin in sharepoint to inhouse

Tags: permissions, administration

My company has an IT company running their sharepoint site. This seems a bit overkill, as it's only used for document storage(500-1000 office docs) - so all this company is doing is handing out permissions and making new users.

So I wanna pull this inhouse instead. But how is this done? How do I take over the full control of our sharepoint site?

Comment: where that site is hosted? office 365 or on IT company's Farm?

Comment: Its on Office 365.. probably,to be honest im not 100% sure

Comment: Is there a way I can check that myself?

Comment: Ask the company...

Comment: They charge 180$ pr Call, so ofcourse I would like if there were an option to check myself :D

Comment: You can check if it is o365 or on prem from the browser. Check my answer : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153709/how-to-identify-the-public-web-site-is-sharepoint-online-or-on-premise/153713#153713

Comment: @Akhoy I'm not sure what to read from the header though

   MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4420

   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0

Does this mean our 365 is "online" and can be overtaken by changing Global admin, or is it on a farm.. and I'm screwed :P

Comment: It's on o365 :)

Comment: @Akhoy Hmm, when I used the described message I got that. But when looking in sharepoint designer I just discovered that it says 5(15.0.0.4455) and llS/8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sharepoint hosted either on office 365 or on prem or that company hosted it on azure.

But you have to check with company or read the agreement your company did with them.once you know what type of sharepoint deployment then you can take control of it.

- if it 365 hosted controlled by them you can either buy 365 subscription and move your site from them to your
- if it is on prem then you have to deploy a sharepoint farm in house then ask them for the site back and restore in ur farm.
  -

Comment: If it's hosted on 365 online, is it possible to just make my account a global admin - and then I'd just delete their user? - or does that mess up license/billing

Comment: Yes, it is easy to add ur self as global admin...then remove everybody you don't want